# HTTP to HTTPS too many redirections

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cwp

I encountered this strange issue that whenever I add this most generally used htaccess code, I get too many redirections.

Scenario:

```
+public_html
|
|--- WordPress 1
|--- .htaccess
 --+ /blog
   |
   |--WordPress 2
    --.htaccess
```

.htaccess (WordPress 2)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.test/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
  
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Whenever I add HTTPS redirection code in any of the htaccess it gives Too many redirects.

It seems RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off this condition is always getting true and that's why (Checked here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)
How can I tackle this?

Notes: WordPress home/site URL is set correctly: https://domain.test/blog for WordPress 2

Edit:
Solution: The issue was Flexible mode in Cloudflare. When I set it to Full SSL mode in Cloudflare the issue was solved.

Comment: Do any of these installations maybe have a post named 'blog'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case as manually entering HTTPS for /blog WordPress works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was Flexible mode in Cloudflare. When I set it to Full SSL mode in Cloudflare the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your file '.htaccess Wordpress 2 you have a mistake.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.test/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is causing you problems. What happens:

1. Say, your input is `http://www.domain.test/blog`
2. The line `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` will trigger, since you are using `http` and not `https`
3. Meaning the newxt rewrite rule gets executed.

This part: `^(.*)$` means:

1. take everything from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`). (In your case that is `blog`.)
2. Put that part into a variable. That is the parentheses part `(.*)` means. It will make the 'everything' part available as variable `$1`
3. Putting this together, you should now replace `$1` with `blog`. The end result being:

   https://www.domain.test/blog/blog/

So, you should start by removing the `blog` part of your third line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.test/$1 [R=301,L]
```

New problems might occur, but you have to fix this first.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. Yes this issue will occur but main HTTPS issue I was able to solve by setting Strict mode in Cloudflare